# Как увеличить и отцентровать выбранный маршрут?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Вот отличный [пример](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple), копирую код и вставляю в свой, но у меня *zoom* не меняется. Если *drag-and-drop* методом поставить маркер далеко, то приходится вручную увеличивать, а хочу, как в примере.

В сети на этот вопрос люди советуют поменять опцию класса `DirectionsRenderer preserveViewport:true`.
Но эта настройка работает не так, как в примере.

Как решить эту проблему?

Вот мой код:

```
    function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.2397803, 76.90938740000001);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: latlng,
    scrollWheel: false,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    draggable: true,
    map: map,
    panel: document.getElementById('distance-panel')
});

directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
});

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
  service.route({
    origin: origin,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    //If true, instructs the Directions service to avoid toll roads where possible. Optional.
    avoidTolls: true
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      display.setDirections(response);
  } else {
      alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
  }
});
};


function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';

    console.log("start_address: ", result.routes[0].legs[0]);
    console.log("end_address: ", result.routes[0].legs[0].end_address);

    var endLocation = result.routes[0].legs[0].end_location;
    var startLocation = result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;

    map.setCenter({lat: endLocation.H, lng: startLocation.L});
    map.setZoom(16);

}
$( "#getRoute" ).click(function() {
   displayRoute($( "#toAddress" ).val(), $( "#fromAddress" ).val(), directionsService, directionsDisplay);

});

};
```

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, ВАШ рабочий пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение получилось гораздо элегантнее чем я думал.

```
Только все должно быть вот в таком формате:

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var start_location = result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
var end_location = result.routes[0].legs[0].end_location;

bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(start_location.lat(), start_location.lng()));
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(end_location.lat(), end_location.lng()));
// отображает карту по центру по выбранному маршруту
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```